Is there a rule for using parentheses or brackets after the summation symbol to indicate what is included in the sum?
Using parentheses or brackets removes ambiguity but is it necessary?

There are ambigous cases , for example "$a:bc$" , which can mean $\frac{a}{bc}$ or $\frac{a}{b}c$

If you think it might be ambiguous, add the parentheses. The point is to communicate something to another human being in the end.
